# How to use named Array element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].join([separator = ','])
```

results in "a,b,c"

```
[separator=',']
```

is obviously valid.

How can I create *myjoin* that uses *myseparator* as some kind of parameter. How can one use this named array parameter, how to access it and where it can be usable?

My primary intention isn't really crating *myseparator* but trying to understand this construction since I didn't bump into it before.

Sorry if duplicating question, I just haven't found any other resource.

Comment: It might be valid (in sloppy mode), but I doubt it works the way you expect it to.

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c'].join(",")` works too and so does `var sep = ","; ['a', 'b', 'c'].join(sep)`
Your code works because the toString of the array is delimited by comma but since you only have one separator, it uses that value

Comment: `[separator=',']` is valid, but it means "store the string `','` in the variable `separator`, then use the value from that assignment as the sole item in an array". Then, `join` coerces that array to a string, `','`. The variable `separator` is not at all associated with the array statement that lexically surrounds its assignment, other than the fact that the value of `separator` happens to be the same as the value of the array's only item.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: It's in the MDN documentation @Pointy.

Comment: @Andy ah - that's the meta-syntax they use. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement is syntactically correct, but it's achieving its result in a weird way.

The `.join()` method does take an argument, and the argument is expected to be a string. If it's not a string, it's *coerced* to a string by normal means. In your code, the array `[separator=',']` when converted from an array will be the string `","`.

The equivalent (less weird) way to do the join would be

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].join(",");
```

Note that the embedded assignment to the variable `separator` is a side effect that does not have anything to do with the behavior of the `.join()` function. The fact that that assignment took place before the function call (to `.join()`) is undetectable by that function.

*edit* — the MDN documentation for the `.join()` method describes it like this:

```
str = arr.join([separator = ','])
```

That's an unfortunately confusing notational convention used throughout the MDN documentation. The bracketed `separator = ','` is a meta-syntactic convention meaning that the function accepts one *optional* argument. The fact that it's optional is indicated by the square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I think you are trying to define the separator before you hit the `join` method. Does this look like it?

```
var separator = ',';
['a', 'b', 'c'].join(separator);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function myJoin(arr, sep) {
  return arr.join(sep);
}

myJoin(arr, '-'); // "a-b-c"
myJoin(arr, '**'); // "a**b**c"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2su8nc0m/)

Comment: Can the downvoter contribute something more explicit by explaining the issue with this answer?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know too since this explicitly answers the OP's question.